# Why is AngularJS printing "> " in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get AngularJS to parse all the data given to it in JSON from a Spring rest controller. I am able to get the data to parse and everything but whenever angular repeats in the loop it print a text of ">     " on the page.

My javascript

```
var HOST_SERVER = "http://localhost:8080";


angular.module('exchange', [])
    .controller("Book", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get(HOST_SERVER + "/exchange/get")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.books = response.data;
            });
    });
```

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="exchange">
<head>
    <title>The Book Exchange</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsengine01.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- test stuff-->
    <div data-ng-controller="Book">
        <div data-ng-repeat="book in books">>
            <h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
            <h4>By {{book.author}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested the controllers and they return the appropriate json responses but I can post those as well if it would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second `>` in your code that is being repeated...

```
<body>
    <!-- test stuff-->
    <div data-ng-controller="Book">
        <div data-ng-repeat="book in books">> <!-- Remove the second '>' -->
            <h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
            <h4>By {{book.author}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```